# GNU Scientific Library doesn't work with M1 chip

Tags: c++, macos, gsl

I am trying to run a C++ program which uses GSL.

I am running it on my Mac which has the M1 chip and iOS 12.4.

I installed GSL using Brew in Mac Terminal:

`$ brew install GSL`

When I try to compile the program, I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgsl.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgslcblas.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_gsl_ran_gaussian", referenced from:
      population::initialize_two(Cytoplasm) in population.o
      population::evolve() in population.o
  "_gsl_rng_alloc", referenced from:
      population::population(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in population.o
  "_gsl_rng_mt19937", referenced from:
      population::population(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in population.o
  "_gsl_rng_set", referenced from:
      population::population(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in population.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

From what I understand, GSL is supposed to work with the M1 chip.

I am very new to C++, so I am not sure where to start.

EDIT:

when I run

`$ brew info gsl`

I get the following output:

```
gsl: stable 2.7.1 (bottled)
Numerical library for C and C++
https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/
/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/2.7.1 (290 files, 10.2MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-06-23 at 10:37:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/gsl.rb
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
==> Analytics
install: 3,770 (30 days), 12,230 (90 days), 51,294 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,564 (30 days), 5,263 (90 days), 23,227 (365 days)
build-error: 1 (30 days)
```

I just compiled using the

`make` command.

Thanks :)

Comment: `ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgsl.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64` kinda gives the game away...

Comment: Please click [edit] and add in the actual command you used to compile, and also the output from `brew info gsl` Thank you.